# Importing SVG as Grease Pencil

Tags: python, import, grease-pencil, svg

I am trying to import an SVG file and because when using the `bpy.ops.import_curve.svg()` the imported file seems not correct, I would like to use the `bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_import_svg()`. When testing it from menu, SVG is imported correctly.

The issue is, that nothing happens when I use `bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_import_svg` from Python, the only thing I can see is that the operator writes `{'FINISHED'}` and nothing is inserted into the scene.

Also the `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected` is empty after the import. Below is the line I used for the import, I tried many combinations of the filepath/directory, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
     bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_import_svg(filepath="/tmp/file.svg", scale=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, i have figured it out, based on the source code of the [corresponding C code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/editors/io/io_gpencil_import.cc#L111). One must provide the `files` array with list of filenames, together with the `directory` string, setting the path, `filepath` must also be provided but can be an empty string:

```
bpy.ops.wm.gpencil_import_svg(filepath="", directory="/path", files=[{"name":"filename.svg"}])
```